# Need alternative to local or remote goto/destinations with merged documents

Tags: pdf, itext

BACKGROUND

I have a java program that analyzes data and creates a pdf report using itext 5.

I recently had to add a summary of major problems at the start of the document so a user would not have to read over a hundred pages to find problems.  Problems are only discovered when serially looking through the data.

I solved the problem by creating 3 pdf documents and then merging them, a start/title pdf, the summary of problems pdf, and the body or analysis pdf.  (Basically splitting the original document at the point I wanted to insert the summary)

I use PdfReader and PdfCopy to combine the documents.  I am able to keep the chapter bookmarks OK.

THE PROBLEM

As I encounter a significant problem I add it to the 'summary' document.  I want to add a link in the summary to point to the problem in the body.

I tried to use Chunk.setLocalDestination and setLocalGoto but realized why that did not work, so I tried using setLocalDestination and setRemoteGoto (with and without 'file://'), but that did not work either.  (Also, I used the final pdf document name in the RemoteGoto, not the temporary pdf document name.)

I do not want to use bookmarks because that seems wrong and would not look right.

I am hoping someone could suggest an alternate method or make a suggestion.

To recap, in my current code a create a Chunk with setLocalDestination and that chunk goes into the 'body' document.  At the same time I create a setRemoteGoto which is put into the summary document.  I was hoping when they were combined the link would work, but when the link is clicked, you go to the first page of the combined document.

Thanks.....

PS I have both iText in action books

CLARIFICATION 3/5/2014

What I was calling 'bookmarks' are really Chapter class entities that are inserted into sections of the 3 documents as they are being created.

After saving the 3 documents, PdfReader is used to open each and PdfCopy is used to put them into a new, final document.

I get the data from the Chapters, which creates the 'bookmarks' on the left side of the Pdf reader used by the user, e.g. Acrobat Reader.

```
int thisPdfPages = reader.getNumberOfPages();
reader.consolidateNamedDestinations();
java.util.List<HashMap<String, Object>> bookmarks = SimpleBookmark.getBookmark(reader);
if (bookmarks != null) {
    if (pageOffset != 0) {
        if (debug3) auditLogger.log("Shifting pages by " + pageOffset );
        SimpleBookmark.shiftPageNumbers(bookmarks, pageOffset, null);
    }
    masterBookmarks.addAll(bookmarks);
}
for (int i = 0; i < thisPdfPages;) {
    page = copy.getImportedPage(reader, ++i);
    stamp = copy.createPageStamp(page);
    // add page numbers
    ColumnText.showTextAligned(stamp.getUnderContent(), Element.ALIGN_CENTER, new Phrase(String.format("page %d of %d", start + i, totalPages)), 297.5f, 28, 0);
    stamp.alterContents();
    copy.addPage(page);
}
PRAcroForm form = reader.getAcroForm();
if (form != null) {
    copy.copyAcroForm(reader);
}
```

When analyzing the data I have 2 documents open, a base document which contains all the details and a summary document which contains notable events over some thresholds.

```
//NOTE section is part of the 'body' document
//NOTE summaryPhrase is a part of the 'summary' document
String linkName = "summaryPf_" + networkid ;
//create Link target
section.add(new Chunk("CHANGE TO EMPTY STRING WHEN WORKING").setLocalDestination( linkName ));
//create Link
Chunk linkChunk = new Chunk( "[Link]  " );
Font linkFont = new Font( regularFont );
linkFont.setColor(BaseColor.BLUE);
linkFont.setStyle( Font.UNDERLINE );
linkChunk.setFont( linkFont );
boolean useLocal = true;
// both local and remote goto's fail
if (useLocal) {
    linkChunk.setLocalGoto( linkName);
} else {
    // all permutations of setting filename fail, 
    // but it does bring up a permissions dialog when the link is clicked.
    //String remotePdfName = "file://./" + pdfReportName ;
    //String remotePdfName = "file://" + pdfReportName ;
    //String remotePdfName = "file:" + pdfReportName ;
    String remotePdfName = pdfReportName ;
    linkChunk.setRemoteGoto( remotePdfName, linkName);
}
// add link to summary document
summaryPhrase.add( linkChunk );
summaryPhrase.add( String.format("There were %d devices with ping failures", summaryCount));
summaryPhrase.add( Chunk.NEWLINE );
}
```

If I use setLocalGoto, when you click the link in the final document you goto the first page.

If I use setRemoteGoto, a dialog ask permission to go to a document, but the document fails to open, tried several permutations on filename.

Comment: If you have the bookmarks working, you have info about the explicit destinations. If you have explicit destination, you can use these in a link annotation, can't you? If not, you'll have to clarify, because right now it's hard to understand when you say "it's not working."

Comment: Thanks for your response Bruno.  I think is made an error in my use of words.  What I have are Chapters.    When I inititally did the merge/concatenation the table of contents worked for only the first document.

Comment: If the table of contents is part of the separate documents, then it's only normal that you can't "merge" them. That's inherent to PDF. You should make the TOC for the complete (merged) document, not for the separate documents. If this doesn't answer your question, please clarify, because your question still isn't clear.

Comment: Something is dramataically wrong.  I spent an  hour editing the original question clarifying what I am doing and what the problem is.  I am sure I saved the edit but now I do not see it..... ????  I will check further, please don't reply until I post more data.  The comment above by me was the start but then I realized I could not format a comment or add code.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie (@Bruno Lowagie) I have added further clarifications to my question.  I am not make a table of contents, but I am trying to create links in one document to anchors in another document and hope that when the two documents are merged the links will work.